Flex box with 2 divs (1 image and 1 text) bound by screen rather than container div
I've got an info box with movie/tv show data and figure it's fairly straightforward. But I've been battling this flexbox for (way too many) hours. I've tried countless solutions on here and elsewhere, but none work.
the box is simple: An image div (left) and text div (right) wrapped in a container.
I've encounter 3 problems:

When the (right-side) text div fills with text, it widens then drops below the image div. Text only starts wrapping when it's on its own line. (I expect it to wrap without dropping the div below.)
Assigning the text div a width (ex: 70%) solves the issue, but then it drops to the next line as soon as it gets below that width (when I shrink the browser window).
On mobile screens, the text div (which is below the image on mobile) only takes up the width that I assign it (ex: 70%).

I want the text div to take up the remaining space in the same row, which is what I thought it was supposed to do. I thought the 2 child divs are bound by the container div, no the full window.
The box is simple. Using Fallout as an example:


div.tv-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
div.tv-image {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
div.tv-details {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
dl {
    display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    }
dt {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    }
dd {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    }
<div class="tv-wrapper">
    <div class="tv-image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="300px"></div>
    <div class="tv-details">
    <h2>Fallout (2024)</h2>
    <dl>
        <dt>Network:</dt><dd> Prime Video</dd>
        <dt>Number of Seasons:</dt><dd> 1</dd>
        <dt>Status:</dt><dd> Returning Series</dd>
        <dt>Genre:</dt><dd> Sci-Fi &amp; Fantasy, Action &amp; Adventure, Mystery</dd>
        <dt>Creator:</dt><dd> Geneva Robertson-Dworet, Graham Wagner</dd>
        <dt>Main Cast:</dt><dd> Ella Purnell, Aaron Moten, Moisés Arias, Walton Goggins</dd>
        <dt>Overview:</dt><dd> The story of haves and have-nots in a world in which there’s almost nothing left to have. 200 years after the apocalypse, the gentle denizens of luxury fallout shelters are forced to return to the irradiated hellscape their ancestors left behind — and are shocked to discover an incredibly complex, gleefully weird, and highly violent universe waiting for them.</dd>
    </dl>
    </div>
</div>



I've tried every combination of flex wraps, flex rows, justify-contents, floats, etc.
I want the info box to be responsive to screen size and I want it to take up the full screen. I want the (left side) image div to take up 1/3 of the wrapper div and the (right-side) text div to take up 2/3 of the wrapper div. I want the text div to drop below the image div when the screen gets smaller.
And I've tried to keep the CSS as simple as possible until I get this figured out.
(The background colors in attached image are just for troubleshooting.)



You don't need to combine floats with flex here — floats are designed to work with text that literally wraps an image (when a part of text moves below an image while the rest of it stays in line with it).
And in your case, as far as I understand, it's enough to simply work with blocks: on larger screens put them on one row, on smaller screens move the text down and center the image. And there're several ways to do it.
The solution I would use is to add media queries like that:
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* here goes smaller screens styling */
}

This way you could remove flex-wrap: wrap; from your default (desktop) styles and add it only to the mobile part, along with some other properties.
But there's also another option. I've created a fiddle for you here with comments. What basically happens there is the following:

the image box is always 300px,
the text box may take all the available space within the parent container (we use flex-basis and flex-grow magic for it),
the text box also has a minimal width — it lets it jump to the next "row", below the image, as soon as it reaches the specified value, 500px in my example,
the image box styling also has margin: 0 auto; line which is responsible for placing it to the center of a parent when it stays alone in its row: but if you'd rather like to put an image itself to the center of its tv-image container (if you're planning to use a background color or, say, some borders), you'll have to remove this line and move the "centering logic" into the container.

Other notes, a bit off-topic:

I added alt attribute to the image tag, it's just a nice practice for accessibility,
setting max-width: 100% for all images is good to prevent them from overflowing parent containers,
you may avoid adding tag names to your CSS rules, it's more handy to describe styling using class names only, so .tv-image is better than div.tv-image.

Really hope it helps!

Oh wow, thank you so much!  For your help and the explanation.
(And now I understand float better as well. )
This works perfectly.
I appreciate the extra tips as well. (And good point, I do use alt tags. I removed them so my example was less cluttered. But I'm big on accessibility. ✌)
